# Git, sub-repos & external libs for web development - best strategy once and for all?

Tags: git, plugins, content-management-system, git-submodules

This is such a common scenario that there must be a sensible solution, yet despite pages of reading and copious Git gymnastics, my brain aches and I'm unable to make this work...

I'm working with Wordpress, though this will fit most website dev scenario's.  I want to manage the site install with a git repo and also manage various WP plugins, jQuery plugins and  other code bits in separate repos which can easily be pulled/pushed from their external sources.    Seems simple enough until you look at the details...

## The criteria

**"Subfolders" criterion**
The folder for each plugin should not be bound to the root folder of its source repo.  Many repos have multiple nested folders such as "my-repo-name/...", "dev/", "test/", "src/" where the contents of the later is the thing required.  This is important to keep the referencing URLs clean and to minimise publicly available rubbish.

**"No Proxys" criterion** 
The ideal solution would not require additional intermediary branches or repos.  Pushing changes to a plugin's external source should be simple and not require multiple intermediary merges/pushes.

**"Real Files" criterion** 
Ideally the outer repo for the whole website should actually contain the files of the plugins' subrepos (ie no "submodules").  I could be persuaded away from this one though...

**"Publishing" criterion** 
It must play well with rsync and/or git push'ing to the live server

## I've looked at these five solutions

**Git Submodules** Simple enough for making changes and pushing/pulling but submodules fail on the "Subfolders" and "Real File" criteria

**Git read-tree/subtree merge** Solves the "Real Files" problem and `read-tree` actually lets you reference a branch's subfolder but when I did so and tried to merge changes on master back upstream, Git failed to remember that it came from a subfolder and merged master's whole structure into the ext libs tracking branch...so FAIL on this criterion.

**Apenwarrs subtree extension [(here)](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree)**
Great for the "Real Files" criterion and fairly simple to push/pull until you want to enforce the "Subfolders" rule.  At best it then seems to require intermediary branches where you split out the folder you want from the remote tracking branch and then add this as a subtree to your master branch.  I didn't have much luck merging/pushing changes on master back to the source repo.  I still think there might be possibility here...

**Symbolic links with external repo**
Great solution until GIT stopped following symlinks.  Now it fails on "Real Files" and "Publishing" criteria

**Nested repos**
Somewhere I saw an SO answer where if you explicitly `git add` a folder which contains another repo and include the trailing slash, git will NOT submodule it but instead track the individual files.  This seemed promising but it fails on the "Subfolders" criterion.

## What next?

I've seen references to "sparse checkout" - or perhaps a something involving branch pruning.  I'm hoping to avoid a solution that involves shell scripts or is so complex that it requires me to re-learn it every time (infrequent) I make a change to a plugin.  It needs to be easier than maintaining a separate repo for each plugin and copying back and forth from the main CMS installation.

Surely someone has a simple functional way to make this common dev scenario work??  Thanks in advance for the help...

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you've been thinking about this, and I am only a novice at git, but my first instinct would be to add .gitignore to the plugins directory and have each plugin have it's own git repo. You could do the same for themes. So I guess this is more of a question than an answer - why wouldn't this simple approach work?

Comment: Thanks Mahalie.  One reason is that a lot of repos dont put their core files in the root and often add unit test and other folders in the master branch.  This leads to ugly, long URLs esp for JS libs as well as public access to lots of unnecessary files.  The other reason is that if you use git to push to a live server (by cloning the local repo and then pushing from local and merging on the server) then this would require manually pushing/merging  each repo.  Being that everyone is using GIT nowadays even for jquery plugs, a typical website theme might have 10 or more repos in it.